# ReactJs - getInitialState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing with ReactJs, and i have this simple code

```js
var User = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
            <li>
                {this.props.email}
            </li>
        );
     }
});

var UserList = React.createClass({
    reload: function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', "http://localhost:64501/Home/GetUsers", true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ data: result });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }.bind(this);

        xhr.send();
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: [
                { email: "bob@gmail.com", id: "1" },
                { email: "boby@gmail.com", id: "2" }
            ]
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        window.setInterval(this.reload, 3000);  
    },

    render: function () {       
        if (this.props.data != null) {
            var userNodes = this.props.data.map(function (user) {               
                return (
                    <User email={user.email} key={user.id } ></User>
                );
            });

            return (
                <div>
                    <ul>{userNodes}</ul>                    
                 </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            console.log("this.props.data is null");
            return null;
        }        
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<UserList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I got 2 issues :
1 - the datas returned by `getInitialState` function are not rendered by the component.
2 - setState does not refresh the component in the reload function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading `this.props.data` and you should be reading `this.state.data`.

Note the difference between component properties, which come externally, and component internal state.

Just replace all `this.props.data` with `this.state.data` and your code should work.

Comment: i forgot to replace the if test. It's working. Thanks